# kafka issue while connecting to zookeeper (kubernetes-kafka:1.0-10.2.1)

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-statefulset

I have used this document for creating kafka https://kow3ns.github.io/kubernetes-kafka/manifests/

able to create zookeeper, facing issue with the creation of kafka.getting error to connect with the zookeeper.

this is the manifest i have used for creating
for kafka:

https://kow3ns.github.io/kubernetes-kafka/manifests/kafka.yaml
for Zookeeper

https://github.com/kow3ns/kubernetes-zookeeper/blob/master/manifests/zookeeper.yaml

**The logs of the kafka**

```
 kubectl logs -f pod/kafka-0 -n kaf
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,535] INFO KafkaConfig values:
        advertised.host.name = null
        advertised.listeners = null
        advertised.port = null
        authorizer.class.name =
        auto.create.topics.enable = true
        auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
        background.threads = 10
        broker.id = 0
        broker.id.generation.enable = true
        broker.rack = null
        compression.type = producer
        connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
        controlled.shutdown.enable = true
        controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
        controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
        controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        create.topic.policy.class.name = null
        default.replication.factor = 1
        delete.topic.enable = false
        fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
        group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        host.name =
        inter.broker.listener.name = null
        inter.broker.protocol.version = 0.10.2-IV0
        leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
        leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
        listener.security.protocol.map = SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,TRACE:TRACE,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
        listeners = PLAINTEXT://:9093
        log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
        log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
        log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
        log.cleaner.enable = true
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
        log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
        log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
        log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
        log.cleaner.threads = 1
        log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
        log.dir = /var/lib/kafka
        log.dirs = /tmp/kafka-logs
        log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.interval.ms = null
        log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
        log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
        log.message.format.version = 0.10.2-IV0
        log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
        log.preallocate = false
        log.retention.bytes = -1
        log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
        log.retention.hours = 168
        log.retention.minutes = null
        log.retention.ms = null
        log.roll.hours = 168
        log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
        log.roll.jitter.ms = null
        log.roll.ms = null
        log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
        log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
        max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip.overrides =
        message.max.bytes = 1000012
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        min.insync.replicas = 1
        num.io.threads = 8
        num.network.threads = 3
        num.partitions = 1
        num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
        num.replica.fetchers = 1
        offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
        offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
        offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
        offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
        offsets.retention.minutes = 1440
        offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
        offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
        offsets.topic.replication.factor = 3
        offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
        port = 9092
        principal.builder.class = class org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.DefaultPrincipalBuilder
        producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        queued.max.requests = 500
        quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.window.num = 11
        quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
        replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
        replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
        replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
        replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
        replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
        replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
        replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        replication.quota.window.num = 11
        replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
        sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
        security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
        socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
        socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.client.auth = none
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        unclean.leader.election.enable = true
        zookeeper.connect = zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181
        zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
        zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        zookeeper.set.acl = false
        zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,569] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,570] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,579] INFO Starting ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.9-1757313, built on 08/23/2016 06:50 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:host.name=kafka-0.kafka-hs.kaf.svc.cluster.local (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_131 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b05.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/guava-18.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0-b05.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b05.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b05.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.8.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.8.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.inject-1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.inject-2.5.0-b05.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.24.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.24.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.24.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.24.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-guava-2.24.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.24.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.24.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1-sources.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1-test-sources.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.0.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.11.8.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zkclient-0.10.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:os.version=5.4.141-67.229.amzn2.x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:user.name=kafka (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:user.home=/home/kafka (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,583] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,584] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@5e0826e7 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,591] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,592] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException: Unable to connect to zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:72)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1228)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:157)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:131)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:106)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:88)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:326)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:187)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.<init>(StaticHostProvider.java:61)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:445)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:380)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:70)
        ... 10 more
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,594] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,597] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-10-19 05:37:14,597] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException: Unable to connect to zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:72)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1228)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:157)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:131)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:106)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:88)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:326)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:187)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:39)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.<init>(StaticHostProvider.java:61)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:445)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:380)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:70)
        ... 10 more
```

[Crash-Loop-Kafka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1FuF.png)
[kafka deployed manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ang7w.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Kafka and Zookeeper deployments are running in the `kaf` namespace according to your screenshots, presumably you have set this up manually and applied the configurations while in that namespace? Neither the Kafka or Zookeeper YAML files explicitly state a namespace in metadata, so will be deployed to the active namespace when created.

Anyway, the Kafka deployment YAML you have is hardcoded to assume Zookeeper is setup in the `default` namespace, with the following line:

```
          --override zookeeper.connect=zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181 \
```

Change this to:

```
          --override zookeeper.connect=zk-cs.kaf.svc.cluster.local:2181 \
```

and it should connect. Whether that's by downloading and locally editing the YAML file etc.

Alternatively deploy Zookeeper into the `default` namespace.

I also recommend looking at other options like [Bitnami Kafka Helm charts](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka/#installing-the-chart) which deploy Zookeeper as needed with Kafka, manages most of the connection details and allows for easier customisation. It is also kept far more up to date.

Comment: I'd suggest the Bitnami Kafka operate over the Helm Charts

Comment: Hey Thanks! for the suggestion.  I applied the both the files in default namespace. Its running but It is not in the ready state.  "Readiness probe fails"  "https://kow3ns.github.io/kubernetes-kafka/manifests/kafka.yaml "